# Is this the correct equation for the cylinder? If we add mass to the end of a cylindrical structure, what kind of equation do we get?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I am a high school student so unfortunately my English level and physics level are not very high.

I've seen that the moment of inertia applies to rods and cylinders is that true? and I think the moment of inertia will increase if we add mass to the ends, but I can't see it as an equation because my mathematical power is not enough, it's still witchcraft to me.

My particular question is:

1. Does the first equation apply to the cylinder? so if there was a box like that, would it be valid in it?
2. What would be an equation in 2 cases?

[image]

For the second case I didn't write down the length of where the mass is added, but it could be a general length small l.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia

Comment: for a cylinder around a perpendicular axis $$I_1 = \frac{m}{12} \ell^2 + \frac{m}{3} r^2 $$